# custom struct & relational overload generating error

Tags: c++, templates

I've got the following code and am getting the error: 
"error C2676: binary '>' : 'const Car' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator"

It's popping up on the: if (vec[i] > returnValue) /.../ line

I get that it might be confused about how to compare the Car struct but shouldn't that last callback/overload function take care of that?  Suggestions?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Car {
    std::string name;
    int weight;
    int airbags;
};

//callback for typical compairsons
template <typename Type>
int CmpCallBack(Type one, Type two) {
    if (one < two) return -1;
    if (one == two) return 0;
    if (one > two) return 1;
}

//itterate through vec<Type> and return max value
template <typename Type>
Type FindMax(std::vector<Type> const &vec, int (cmpFn)(Type one, Type two) = CmpCallBack) {
    Type returnValue = new Type; //is this the right way to initialize this var?
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if (vec[i] > returnValue) {
            returnValue = vec[i];
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}

//callback for the custom "Car" struct
int CarAirComp(Car one, Car two) {
    if (one.airbags < two.airbags) return -1;
    if (one.airbags == two.airbags) return 0;
    if (one.airbags > two.airbags) return 1;
}

int main () {

        //build a vector of Car types
    std::vector<Car> cars;
    Car x;
    x.airbags = 5;
    x.name = "car one";
    Car y;
    y.airbags = 3;
    y.name = "car two";
    Car z;
    z.airbags = 1;
    z.name = "car three";
    cars.push_back(x);
    cars.push_back(y);
    cars.push_back(z);

        //test function
    Car returnVal = FindMax(cars, CarAirComp);

    std::cout << "value: " << returnVal.name << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have `operator >` defined for `Car`.  The compiler does not know how to evaluate `(vec[i] > returnValue)`.  If you define this operator, you should be fine:

```
struct Car {
    ...
    bool operator >(const Car & other) const 
    {
       // compare them however you like
       return weight < other.weight; 
    }
}
```

Additionally, you will need to change this:

```
Type returnValue = new Type;
```

to

```
Type returnValue;  // this default constructs the object
```

**Update:**

Since you have a compare function available, you do not need to write an `operator >`.  Instead, use your compare function:

```
if(cmpFn(vec[i], returnValue) > 0) {
    returnValue = vec[i];
}
```

Comment: Would the above "bool operator >" be consistent across templates?  I would like the user to be able to compare Car structs however he/she would like...  That's why I was including the optional comparison function "CmpCallBack".  When I called the "FindMax" in main and passed it the "CarAirCmp" parameter (callback for the struct) I expected that to overload the ">" operator and take care of that error.  Do I instead put the comparison info within the Car struct?  I am missing something here...

Comment: Fair enough, then you should be using that compare function instead of 'vec[i] > returnValue'.  I'll update the response to reflect that.

Comment: That's it.  Didn't realize i needed to call it in function form inside.  Now I've got it.  THanks!